# Arduino mega entry point address

Tags: arduino

I am working on a fresh arduino mega rev3 device.

I want to understand how it works and i need to disassemble flash memory dump.
I have seen that bootloader starts at address 0x3E000

What i want to know now is where does the main program starts in memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where the bootloader starts (if it's used) depends on fuse settings. If you have compact bootloader, you can use smaller `BOOTSZ`. If you're using `ICSP` header for uploading user program, you don't even need bootloader at all.

Anyway, program starts at `0x0000` on this chip.